# Foreach loop inside foreach loop (Java)

Tags: java, loops

I have the following code:

```
Set<TOrganization> organizations = new LinkedHashSet<TOrganization>();
Set<TRole> roles = new LinkedHashSet<TRole>();
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Requested roles: " + "\n");

//I fill them up with names like Test org A, Test Role A 1

for(TOrganization org : organizations) {
    message.append(" - " + org.getName()+ "\n");
    for(TRole role : roles) {
        if(role.getOrganization().equals(org)) {
            message.append("   - " + role.getName()+ "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print out the roles in separate categories, something like this:

> " - Test org A"
>     " - Test Role A 1"
>     " - Test Role A 2"
>   " - Test org B"
>     " - Test Role B 1"
>     " - Test Role B 2"

But my code always appends the organization name before the roles, like this:

> " - Test org A"
>     " - Test Role A 1"
>   " - Test org A"
>     " - Test Role A 2"
>   " - Test org B"
>     " - Test Role B 1"
>   " - Test org B"
>     " - Test Role B 2"

It seems `message.append(" - " + org.getName()+ "\n");` gets executed whenever the second loop runs. How is that possible?

Edit: I tested it with printlns but the role names are fine. I didn't touch equals() or hashcode(), I'm simply comparing strings with equals(). The problem is that the org names gets appended into the message for each role belonging to them when they should only appear once.

Comment: It's possible if you only have one role per organization. Did you override `hashCode` and `equals` properly?

Comment: Step through your code or add printlns; some assumption you're making is incorrect. Start where you *add* the data.

Comment: @Kevin Or rather, did he override `hashcode` and `equals` improperly! (Since not implementing them at all would be fine.)

Comment: `role.getName()` must be printing the `org.getName()`. Check that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working

```
class TOrganization {

    private String name;

    public TOrganization(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof TOrganization) {
            if (((TOrganization) obj).getName().equals(name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

}

class TRole {

    private TOrganization organization;
    private String name;

    public TRole(TOrganization organization, String name) {
        this.organization = organization;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public TOrganization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<TOrganization> organizations = new LinkedHashSet<TOrganization>();
    Set<TRole> roles = new LinkedHashSet<TRole>();
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Requested roles: " + "\n");

    TOrganization orga = new TOrganization("Test org A");
    TOrganization orgb = new TOrganization("Test org B");

    organizations.add(new TOrganization("Test org A"));
    organizations.add(new TOrganization("Test org B"));
    roles.add(new TRole(orga, "Test Role A 1"));
    roles.add(new TRole(orga, "Test Role A 2"));
    roles.add(new TRole(orgb, "Test Role B 1"));
    roles.add(new TRole(orgb, "Test Role B 2"));

    for (TOrganization org : organizations) {
        message.append(" - " + org.getName() + "\n");
        for (TRole role : roles) {
            if (role.getOrganization().equals(org)) {
                message.append("   - " + role.getName() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(message.toString());
}
```

Output

```
Requested roles: 
 - Test org A
   - Test Role A 1
   - Test Role A 2
 - Test org B
   - Test Role B 1
   - Test Role B 2
```

Your loops are working, you shold fix your classes

Comment: The problem was with comparing the parent organization. I managed to fix it. Thank you everyone! Marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign `roles` in the outer loop (so that it varies when `org` varies)

```
for(TOrganization org : organizations) {
    message.append(" - " + org.getName()+ "\n");

    // like this, you adapt ;)
    roles = org.getRoles();

    for(TRole role : roles) {
        if(role.getOrganization().equals(org)) {
            message.append("   - " + role.getName()+ "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

edit: you should make `Set<TRole> roles = new LinkedHashSet<TRole>();` member of `TOrganization` IMO

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for, sorry if I wasn't clear. I don't want to print out all the roles, only the requested ones, (those come from a jsp page as request parameters). Changing Set<TRole> roles is a bad idea.